# How to interact with my backend's endpoints

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, http

so I have a backend ready to send http responses and requests to the client side, how would one retrieve data from this api or post to it from a client side that can be ran on another computer from the api itself?

Relevant server code:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const path = require('path');
const showdown = require('showdown');
const Blockchain = require('./blockchain');
const PubSub = require('./app/pubsub');
const TransactionPool = require('./wallet/transaction-pool');
const Wallet = require('./wallet');
const TransactionMiner = require('./app/transaction-miner');
const PubSubNub = require('./app/pubsub.pubnub');
//127.0.0.1:6379
const isDevelopment = process.env.ENV === 'development';
//TRY PUBNUB (comment out)
/*const REDIS_URL = isDevelopment ?
  'redis://127.0.0.1:6379' : //try 6379 19289
  'redis://h:p602b6838e89da65c8c4d29a6a4f954452d1ece59c10b27a29ebf9808721cb8e2@ec2-35-153-115-238.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9819'//19289
*/  
const DEFAULT_PORT = 3000;
const ROOT_NODE_ADDRESS = 
`http://localhost:${DEFAULT_PORT}`;

const app = express();
const blockchain = new Blockchain();
const transactionPool = new TransactionPool();
const wallet = new Wallet();
//const pubsub = new PubSub({ blockchain, transactionPool, redisUrl: REDIS_URL });//redis
const pubsub = new PubSubNub({ blockchain, transactionPool, wallet }); // for PubNub //change back to PubSub if issues arise
const transactionMiner = new TransactionMiner({ blockchain, transactionPool, wallet, pubsub });

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/dist')));

//endpoint

//WE ARE TESTING THIS FEATURE!
/*app.post('/test',(req,res)=>
{
    console.log(req);
});*/
//DELETE IF NECESSARY!^^^

app.get('/api/blocks', (req, res) => {
  res.json(blockchain.chain);
});

app.get('/api/blocks/length', (req, res) => {
  res.json(blockchain.chain.length);
});
```

I only wanted to include these endpoints, I just need to know how I can access the data from them in a client sided html file. Thank you!

Comment: Assuming your server actually runs on port 3000, you can access the first endpoint by typing `http://localhost:3000/api/blocks` into your browser's address bar. To do it from another machine in the same network (say your phone), replace `localhost` with your computer's IP address, something like for instance `http://192.168.1.15:3000/api/blocks`. To make your backend accessible to any client worldwide, you need to either a) host it online, for instance on heroku, or b) use port forwarding in your router and the external IP address / a dyndns hostname.

Comment: To access the endpoints from JS running on another server, you need to a) add [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to your express app b) [use fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to make requests to it

Comment: Very useful, if you would put this as an answer for others to see I will upvote it. Thank you for the insight!

Comment: By hosting it online you mean as in a hosting solution correct? I don't want them to be able to see what is written on the api just make http requests/responses to it.

Comment: Yes; I don't mean putting the source on github, I mean having it run on a server online so people can make requests to it.

Comment: sorry, last clarification. If I use the fetch function with cors only downloaded and included into the file, will it automatically let me send data from one computer to another or in this case server and client? No additional steps in a header etc?

Comment: What do you mean "downloaded and included into the file"? Use fetch from where? Who is acting as client?

Comment: what I mean is downloading cors with npm and use it with my express app, I am unsure how to use cors so that cross origin is enabled. Since the browser from client will need to have access to the api on the server separate from their machine

Comment: Did you try the example usage from the docs? https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#simple-usage-enable-all-cors-requests